# Fatal Error on loading specific MySQL Records

Tags: php, mysql

:)
I'm scripting a little web app with a database connection.
If the URL ends with `?tag=whatever` it should only select the records with the categorie (rubrik) `whatever` in this case. It worked but then I rewrote the code a little and now I can't find the mistake. :D

Here's my php code:

```
if(isset($_GET['tag'])) {
    $rubrik = $_GET['tag'];
    $rubrik = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$rubrik);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `rubrik`=`". $rubrik ."` ORDER BY `datum` DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `projects` ORDER BY `datum` DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<a href='project.php?id=".$row["id"]."'><div class='card ". $row["rubrik"] ."'><h4>".$row["name"]."</h4><p>".$row["funktion"]."</p></div></a>";
}
```

If I just open `index.php` it works as usual. But if I type `index.php?tag=whatever`

This error pops up:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Comment: It means `$conn->query($sql);` has failed and there's no results to iterate through. Don't call `$result->fetch_assoc()` when `$result` isn't an object, its most likely going to be a boolean of false.

Comment: As the question is already answered, think about always using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating the string yourself. It is easy to forget sending a variable through `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you update this code. Also you don't need to think about which quote or backtick to use as the prepared statement does this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query uses backtick while it should use single quote. Backtick is for database, table or column identifier while single quote is for string or date literal value.

Change from

```
"SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `rubrik`=`". $rubrik ."` ORDER BY `datum` DESC";
```

to

```
"SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `rubrik`='". $rubrik ."' ORDER BY `datum` DESC";
```

Comment: Maybe also advise OP to start using prepared statements ;)

Answer (score 0):

try updating your code as below

```
    if(isset($_GET['tag'])) {
        $rubrik = $_GET['tag'];
        $rubrik = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$rubrik);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `rubrik`=`". $rubrik ."` ORDER BY `datum` DESC";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
    else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `projects` ORDER BY `datum` DESC";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
    if( $result){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<a href='project.php?id=".$row["id"]."'><div class='card ". $row["rubrik"] ."'><h4>".$row["name"]."</h4><p>".$row["funktion"]."</p></div></a>";
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in your select query

```
"SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `rubrik`=`". $rubrik ."` ORDER BY `datum` DESC";// remove ` symbol in php variable $rubrik
```